# javascript how to call it

Tags: javascript, php

I want to create a text above the input instead of the those echo's
exemple: user submits the email if is valid one text if isnt display another text.

```
if(isset($_POST['submitmailforpw'])){
    $url2 = 'someurl';
     $mailforpw = $_REQUEST['mailforpw'];
     $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");
     if($link){

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }

        $sqlCmd = "Select * from tb where userName='" . $mailforpw . "'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sqlCmd);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $idC = base64_encode($row['idC']);
            $email = base64_encode($mailforpw); 
            $values = $idC . "||" . $email ;
            $url = $url2 . 'values=' . $values ;
            $result = do_post_request($url, "");
            $sendOrNot = explode( '||m7ip||enviado||' , $result);
            if($sendOrNot[1] == "true"){
                echo "enviado";
            }else{
                echo "nao enviado";
            }
        }else{
            //exit(); Não existe na bd
        }
     }else{
        //exit();
     }
}else{
    //exit();
}
```

html

```
           <div>
          <center><form action="" method="post">
            <ul class="form-style-1">
                <li>
                    <label>Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="email" name="mailforpw" class="field-long" required />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input class="button button-xlarge tright noleftmargin nobottommargin fadeInUp animated" type="submit" name="submitmailforpw" value="Submeter" />
                </li>
                <li>
                <div class="required" id="emailNaoEncontrado">
                </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form></center>                
        </div>
```

the js i delete it was working but what i tried was echo '(javascript thing)'; it would work but was to buggy ,tried put php in the end ; put the js echo in the end of teh file and call it via function,etc...
Sry if this question has already been asked and awsered , thx in advance.

Comment: I dont see the Javascript in your code. Did you forget to post it?

Comment: Not polite to say "im kinda in a hurry," specify what you searched and tried instead

Comment: i delete it was working but what i tried was echo '(javascript thing)'; it would work but was to buggy

Comment: i meant i was in a hurry when i was searching , dont know if its less rude , but im sorry didnt meant it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
        if($sendOrNot[1] == "true"){
            echo "enviado";
        }else{
            echo "nao enviado";
        }
```

... store the message in a PHP variable:

```
        if($sendOrNot[1] == "true"){
            $msg = "enviado";
        }else{
            $msg = "nao enviado";
        }
```

Then put the HTML part below the PHP part, and add some PHP inside it, like this:

```
            <li>
                <?php 
                    if (isset($msg)) echo "<div>" . htmlspecialchars($msg) . "</div>";
                ?>
                <label>Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="email" name="mailforpw" class="field-long" required />
            </li>
```

The call to `htmlspecialchars($msg)` is a precaution for when your string has characters that have a special meaning in HTML. But it your string does not have `<` or `&`, then there is no need to include it, and you can just do `$msg`.

Comment: Thank you that made what i wanted to do.